# Partial Derivatives in Einstein Notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces, vectors, tensors

Can someone please check my working, as I am new to Einstein notation:

\begin{align*}
\partial^\mu x^2 &= \partial^\mu(x_\nu x^\nu) \\
&= x^a\partial^\mu x_a + x_b\partial^\mu x^b  \ \ \text{(by product rule and relabelling indices)} \\
&=x^a\delta_\mu^a + x_b\delta_\mu^b \\
&=2x_\mu.
\end{align*}
I'm not sure is the expression in the second term of the second line is correct, as the partial is with respect to the covariant vector but the argument is a contravariant vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writing is not quite correct, although the result is ok. A more precise way (assuming that the metric is constant):

$$ \partial^\mu (x^2) = 
 \partial^\mu (x_\alpha g^{\alpha \nu} x_\nu) = 
 g^{\mu \nu} x_\nu + x_\alpha g^{\alpha \mu} = 2 x_\mu$$
If the metric is not constant you also have to add:
$  (\partial^\mu  g^{\alpha \nu}) x_\alpha x_\nu$ to this.